# Jboss Fuse cluster on external PC

Tags: cluster-computing, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I have a problem with clusering Jboss Fuse. What I have to do is make a cluster with 4 containers but 2 of them have to be on another pc (virtual for now). My qestion is: how can I connect another 2 containers from another pc to my cluster? I'm not asking about deploying anything what will manage my nodes, but simply how to connect reomote containers to my cluser.

Sorry for my byt english and maby a silly qestion but I'm fresh in fuse :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clustering (i.e. load balancing of NMR traffic) of Fuse ESB is done using ActiveMQ Network of Brokers mechanism.

You can read a step-by-step guide on how to setup Fuse ESB cluster here:

fusesource.com/docs/esb/3.5/deploy_guide/DeployESBClusterConfig.html

and more information on how to establish a network of brokers on ActiveMQ (Fuse MB) here:

http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4.1/amq_clustering/FuseMBClusterFaultTolerence.html

The general pattern suggested is to have a pair of master and slave on each host and interconnect the master of host A with the slave of host B, and vice versa.

However, if you interested just in ESB failover setup, it can be done using locking on the shared file system or database (jdbc):

http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4.1/esb_runtime/ESBRuntimeFailoverFileLock.html

Comment: thanks for response but how to connect those B slaves to master of host A?

Comment: There is a `conf/activemq.xml` file for the embedded ActiveMQ broker. For the active/active pair you should use networkConnectors as described here: http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4.1/amq_clustering/Networks-Connectors.html, for the master/slave (i.e. active/passive) use shared lock as described here: http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4.1/amq_clustering/Failover-MasterSlave-JDBC.html

Comment: That is the old way. JBoss Fuse 6.0 onwards has fabric that can do this much easier. You just join your container to the fabric. For example see the loan broker videos here, http://vimeo.com/album/2635012 where you can easily setup a broker cluster.

Comment: join look really nice and easy, thanks for responses :)